# Touch pad or mouse not working on launcher and top panel

Tags: unity, launcher, mouse, touchpad

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and everything was working fine but suddenly the top panel and side bar (launcher) has stop responding to mouse or my touch pad. I can bring the dashboard using keyboard shortcut but can't type anything or click on anything. Same problem is with top panel. For eg. I can't click and open the menu on the top right corner to logout or shutdown, for that I have to press power button on my laptop or Press Alt + F4 to do the task.
I tried to find this problem online but didn't found one anywhere? Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh installation of 13.04 on an Acer Travelmate. Just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also notice the OP has not specified the model of the PC.

Comment: that's true. But one may follow the same instructions for any model and get the problem solved. Anyways I should have been more clear. I thought I will help the OP in some way and he may find a work around.

Comment: You can ask for more information using comments. You can comment on other people's posts when you have enough reputation points.

Comment: what kind of a critic you are..!

Comment: Doesn't work in general though - not at all when this happens on my machine, sadly.